# Selecting an element with a class name in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a small issue with my jQuery and I really can't see what the problem is. I've recently done something similair.

I'm trying to create on onClick event and when once the div has been clicked the div 'mobileAccordian' slides down.

Here is my HTML:

```
   <ul id="left_nav">
    <li>
            <div class="shop_filter">
                    <span>Shop by Department</span>
            </div>
    </li>
    <div class="mobileAccordian">
        <li>
            Item one
        </li>

        <li>
            Item two
        </li>

    </div>
</ul>
```

So my goal is, I want to be able to click on the div.shop_filter, then once it's been clicked on, the 'mobileAccordian' div will run the slideToggle method. I'm assuming the Jquery methods i'm running to find the 'mobileAccordian' are failing to locate it.

Here is my jQuery. I know the click function is running as i've tried adding an alert box.

```
jQuery("#left_nav li:first-child").click(function(){

   jQuery(this).next().find('.mobileAccordian').slideToggle(1000);

});
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Trying to get my head around the difference between the methods. next(), parent(), find().

Thanks.

Comment: `<div>` inside `<ul>` is illegal HTML.

Comment: your html is invalid.... the `div` should be within `li`

Comment: Ok, well i need to hide all of the  <li> other than the first item as the first item is the one that triggers the onClick function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't find the right domElement

So maybe you should try :

```
jQuery("#left_nav li:first-child").click(function(){

   jQuery(this).next('div.mobileAccordian').slideToggle(1000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here http://jsfiddle.net/6ZbVT/1/

Your HTML Markup

```
<ul id="left_nav">
 <li>
   <a href="#" class="shop_filter" >Shop by Department</span>
 </li>
 <li class="mobileAccordian" >
   Item one
 </li>
 <li class="mobileAccordian">
   Item two
 </li>
</ul>
```

Js

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
  jQuery('body').on('click', '.shop_filter', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).parents().eq(1).find('.mobileAccordian').slideToggle(1000);
  });
});
```

Css

```
 .mobileAccordian { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P4mg2/)

For markup geeks...use span inside li and style it as display:block. Now right your code like this

```
<div><ul id="left_nav">
    <li>
            <span class="shop_filter" data-accord="mobileAccordian" style="display:block;">
                    <span>Shop by Department</span>
            </span>
    </li>
</ul>
    <div class="mobileAccordian">
        <li>
            Item one
        </li>

        <li>
            Item two
        </li>

    </div>
</div>
```

Script will be like this

```
jQuery("#left_nav li:first-child").click(function(){ 
   var openAccord = jQuery(this).children('span').attr('data-accord');
   jQuery("."+openAccord).slideToggle(1000); //it will slide all accordians having class mobileAccordian
});
```